# Code unexpectedly accepted by GHC/GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference, typechecking

I don't understand why this code should pass type-checking:

```
foo :: (Maybe a, Maybe b)
foo = let x = Nothing in (x,x)
```

Since each component is bound to the same variable `x`, I would expect that the most general type for this expression to be `(Maybe a, Maybe a)`.  I get the same results if I use a `where` instead of a `let`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: A guess: this is *let polymorphism*.  We would expect the monomorphism restriction to apply, but that only happens when there are class constraints, so as to avoid duplication of computation (because constraints become functions under the hood).  If you give the signature `(Maybe Int, Maybe Double)` and use `x = Just 0` you do get an error, which corroborates this story (recall that numeric literals are polymorphic).

Comment: @luqui I tried `let { foo :: (Maybe Int, Maybe Double) ; foo = let {x=Just 0} in (x,x) }` and it worked, with no error. (?) It even worked with `foo :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => (Maybe a, Maybe b)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Briefly put, the type of `x` gets generalized by `let`. This is a key step in the [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) type inference algorithm.

Concretely, `let x = Nothing` initially assigns `x` the type `Maybe t`, where `t` is a fresh type variable. Then, the type gets generalized, universally quantifying all its type variables (technically: except those in use elsewhere, but here we only have `t`). This causes `x :: forall t. Maybe t`. Note that this is exactly the same type as `Nothing :: forall t. Maybe t`.

Hence, each time we use `x` in our code, that refers to a potentially different type `Maybe t`, much like `Nothing`. Using `(x, x)` gets the same type as `(Nothing, Nothing)` for this reason.

Instead, lambdas do *not* feature the same generalization step. By comparison `(\x -> (x, x)) Nothing` "only" has type `forall t. (Maybe t, Maybe t)`, where both components are forced to be of the same type. Here `x` is again assigned type `Maybe t`, with `t` fresh, but it is not generalized. Then `(x, x)` is assigned type `(Maybe t, Maybe t)`. Only at the top-level we generalize adding `forall t`, but at that point is too late to obtain a heterogeneous pair.

Comment: It’s also maybe worth noting that enabling certain GHC extensions implicitly disables let generalization, namely GADTs or TypeFamilies.

Comment: @AlexisKing, I can't verify that.  The example the OP gives compiles regardless of those extensions.  Example?

Comment: @AlexisKing That doesn't apply here. [`MonoLocalBinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-MonoLocalBinds) applies to only those binding groups with free variables that are either affected by the monomorphism restriction or neither let-bound nor top-level. `Nothing` (as a data constructor) is both not monomorphized and top-level, so the binding group `x = Nothing` gets to be properly generalized.

Comment: @luqui: That’s strange; the [GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html) say that `MonoLocalBinds` is implied by `TypeFamilies` and `GADTs`, and no other extensions. Edit: ah, it’s true but irrelevant to this particular example.

Comment: @HTNW Yes, you’re right, but this answer speaks about let generalization more generally and does not mention that let is only *sometimes* generalized in GHC Haskell.